# Upper triangular matrix can be diagonalized

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be and $n \times n$ block upper triangular matrix of the form, say $$A = \begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} & \cdots & A_{1m}\\0 & A_{22} & \cdots & A_{2m} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & A_{mm}\end{bmatrix}. \\ $$ Each block on the diagonal is upper triangular with the main diagonal being constant in $A_{ii}$, that is the main diagonal consists of $\lambda_i$ and no two blocks will have the same entries on the diagonals. I want to show that I can find an invertible matrix $B$ so that $$B^{-1}AB =\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\0 & A_{22} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & A_{mm}\end{bmatrix},$$ a block diagonal matrix. Now I can definitely show that this is true if $A$ were a $2 \times 2$ upper block triangle matrix matrix and I think I need to somehow use that here but I am having a hard time with these problems. Any hints/answers are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to solve this problem in this way.
Consider first a matrix of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & C\\
0 & B
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ and $B$  are square matrices of order $p$ and $q$
and this matrices do not have characteristic values in common
and where $C$ is a rectangular matrix of dimension $p\times q$.
Under these conditions, the equation $AX-XB=C$ has a unique solution
(see Gantmacher F. R.,  The Theory of Matrices, chapter VIII).

Then we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E_p & X\\
0 & E_q
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & C\\
0 & B
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
E_p & -X\\
0 & E_q
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & B
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Here $E_k$ is a unit matrix of order $k$.

You can now complete the solution by a consistent
application of the above rule.
Starting, for example, with $A_{11}$.